# U-Net image segmentation with multiple masks

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I basically have an image segmentation problem with a dataset of images and multiple masks created for each image, where each mask corresponds to an individual object in the image. All objects are of the same type, but the number of objects may vary. I am trying to train a U-Net with this data.

I could simply combine all the individual masks to form a new mask and feed it into the network as the output, but I feel that useful information related to "recognizing objects individually" might somehow be lost during the process of combining the masks.

Should I, and is there any way to, make use of the additional information? For example, making the network output a variable number of masks instead of one single mask (if that is possible). Might it improve the performance of the network?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same problem as you so I don't have all the answers but if you want to split up your masks, you can one-hot encode them

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
masks_one_hot = to_categorical(masks, num_classes=numMasks)
```

This will split up an image with multiple objects in it into 5 classes so my output vector is:

```
(numChannels, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, numMasks)
```

It might improve the performance depending on what objective function you are using - for this case, I believe categorical crossentropy is appropriate.